# Make array by the use of limit set in PHP

Tags: php

```
$mobile = '66,77,88,99,33,445,555,55';
```

Mentioned variable contains mobile numbers as comma separated values. Limit value 3. If the limit value is 3.So the new array would be

```
$new array  = array(0=>(66,77,88),1=>(99,33,445),2=>(555,55));
```

Means the first array should contain 3 values as comma separated. It's same for other arrays till reach the last array.

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array-chunk):

> Chunks an array into arrays with size elements. The last chunk may
>   contain less than size elements.

And [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode):

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string
>   formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

***Example:***

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$mobile = '66,77,88,99,33,445,555,55';

$mobile = explode(',', $mobile);
$array  = array_chunk($mobile, 3);

print_r($array);
?>
```

***Output:***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 66
            [1] => 77
            [2] => 88
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 99
            [1] => 33
            [2] => 445
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 555
            [1] => 55
        )

)
```